# How to add comments in JBoss standalone.xml?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm using JBoss EAP. I would to add comments in standalone.xml.

How to do this?

Is it like in xml ?

```
<!--
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.2">
<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
</subsystem>
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. The `standalone.xml` file will be overwritten by the server when you make a change with the management API. It's suggested that you make changes through the web console, CLI or another management API.